# How do Feats work?

Tags: character-creation, feats, dead-winter-rpg

From what I understand from the *Dead Winter RPG Rules Guide*, all characters receive  a Racial Feat at every even-numbered level, and a normal Feat at every odd-numbered level. What's the difference between those feats? Can I pick a Racial instead a normal Feat, or a normal Feat instead of a racial one?

Humans, Fae and a few other races get an extra Feat at first level. Must this feat be a normal one, or it can be a racial one?

Also, what are Class Feats? Can I select one of them instead of a Racial, or do I select them in place of Normal Feats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's important to understand the difference between Racial Feats, Normal Feats and Class Feats.

- Normal feats are gained at every odd level, including the first level. Those feats may be any non-racial feat that the character qualifies for, be it a Normal or a Class feat. Normal Feats include things that are not really class- or race-specific, but can be useful to a wide range of adventurers.
- Racial Feats are gained instead of the ability points gained from level advancement in D&D and PF. Every even level (2nd, 4th, 6th,...) a character receives a racial feat—typically something minor (like a +1 on a given skill) plus a big effect tied to your race, usually in the form of a pair of ability points (sometimes a +2 to one ability, sometimes +1 to two). Racial Feats are much more powerful than Normal feats, so they can't be selected at odd levels in place of a Normal feat. If you are *human*, however, you can select a Normal Feat in place of a Racial Feat when you get a even level (but not a Racial feat in place of a normal one, on odd levels).
- Class feats are feats specific to a single class. They are the most powerful way to customize your class features, and they normally come in "feat trees", with the most powerful ones having several lesser feats as prereqs. Most classes have at least a few Class Feat as bonuses at some levels. You can pick a Class Feat in place of a Normal or a Racial feat, but not a Racial or Normal one instead of a Class one.

The Extra Feat granted by Humans, Fae, and all *Dea-Touched* creatures can be selected from the Normal and Class feats avaliable for your character, but not from Racial Feats avaliable for your race.

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Dead Winter RPG.